# Why does Java jump after my return statement

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to build a recursive function as follows:

```
private static int partition(int[] array, int low, int high, int pivot_index){

  // just irrelevant code

  System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 1");
  if(low < high){
    System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 2");
    //some more code
    partition(array,low,high,pivot_index);
  }else{
    System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 3");
    //some more code
    return high;
  }
 System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 0");
 return -1;    

}//partition
```

What startles me is that after running my program and calling this function the compiler prints:

```
point 1 reached; point 2 reached; point 1 reached; point 3 reached. point 0 reached.
```

Which returns the `-1` that crashes the entire logic of the program. I am sure I'm missing something here but how does my program jump after the `if-else` statement. There is no, to my knowledge, case where that `if-statement` doesn't get executed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `if` condition is true, then it doesn't return immediately. After calling `partition`, it will exit the `if` statement, and continue to the end.

If you want the value calculated by the recursion to be returned, you need to change it to

```
if(low < high){
    System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 2");
    //some more code
    return partition(array,low,high,pivot_index);
}
```

Right now, it's just discarding the results of the recursion, and returning the failure value. You need to explicitly say that you want to return that value.

So imagine that you pass in data that will be recursively called one time. The first call will enter the `if` block, and make the recursive call. The second call will enter the `else` block, and return `high`. This passes control back to the initial call, which discards the results of the second call, exits the if statement, and returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` statement in the `if` branch. The call to `partition` just gets executed, its return value gets ignored, and then the function continues, and returns `-1` after the `if` is terminated.

To fix it, just add a `return` call:

```
if(low < high){
    System.out.println("Somehow this point has been reached 2");
    //some more code
    return partition(array,low,high,pivot_index);
}
```